# Turn off encrypted backup on iPhone that has a profile without removing profiles

Tags: ios, backup, encryption, configuration-profiles

I have iPhones that have profiles on them that were password protected profiles and those passwords have been lost.  So we need to wipe the iphones and was hoping to to a backup first and then restore without the profiles on there.  Problem is, it won't let me do a backup without encrypting first.  I have read that in order to not encrypt the backup you need to remove the profiles, but in this case we can't remove the profiles.
Is there any way to turn this encryption off??

Answer (score 2):

When you have a profile that enforces encryption of backups, you really only have three options:

1. Live with the encrypted backups and do nothing.
2. Get someone to remove the profile (or wipe the device along with the profile and start over being careful to not allow profiles that force you into encrypted backups).
3. Somehow exploit a bug or flaw in the security of iOS and bypass this lock. I would expect you to pay big money or have some assistance from NSA-like organization to accomplish this last item unless someone publishes a weakness in iOS that we could take advantage of to bypass the security your iPhone has configured.

As it stands, you will likely have to remove the profile to bypass the restriction that iOS has on not doing a backup in the manner you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access your old encrypted iPhone backups if you can't remember the password. However, iTunes can create a new backup of the iPhone without encrypting the backup, see here for details.
http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4946

Alternatively, you could use a 3rd party app to [backup your iPhone without iTunes.](http://www.wideanglesoftware.com/touchcopy/)

Comment: I think you are confusing the situation where someone tells iTunes to make the encrypted backup (where the user still has a choice) and when a profile is loaded on the iOS device that enforces encrypted backups no matter what copy of iTunes it attempts to back up to. In the latter situation, you delete the profile or you erase the device or you somehow crack into it like the NSA or some other technical wizard might do by exploiting a flaw in the security. Normal users get someone to remove the profile or wipe the device and start over in this case they cannot accept encrypted backups.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found an installed (provisioning) profile is not letting non-encrypted backups to be made, see my write-up here: https://wiitez.blogspot.sg/2016/12/how-to-disable-iphone-requiring-backup.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please don't just insert links, also give a summary or step-by-step of the solution.

Answer (score -2):

There is software that basically spends all day guessing it. I had to do this once when I remembered most of the password but forgot exactly it (forget which one I used). You can put in perimeters o speed things up like 12 characters no numbers no special characters. And when it guesses it you pay for the program and can unhindered the password.